# AWS CloudWatch - How to remove LogLevel and Class that logged in default for .NET Core?

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-cloudwatch

I have success logged the message from my .NET Core API to AWS CloudWatch.

However, I found that the message will automatically consist LogLevel and the class that prints the logs, as below:

```
[Information] Infra.Logging: 
{
    "id": "001",
    "message": "Received Get Data Request",
    "logLevel": "Information"
}
```

I want to get rid of the `[Information]` & `Infra.Logging` from the message. I tried to configure the appsettings as below:

```
"Logging": {
 "IncludeLogLevel": false,
 "IncludeCategory": false,
 "IncludeNewline": false,
 "IncludeException": false,
 "IncludeEventId": false,
 "IncludeScopes": false,
 "LogLevel": {
   "Default": "Trace",
   "System": "Information",
   "Microsoft": "Information"
 }
}
```

But it is not working. Is there any way that can remove the two field that's added automatically into `@message` in the CloudWatch?

Here is how I logged the message:

```
var loggerConfig = new AWSLoggerConfig
{
     LogGroup = logGroup,
     Region = region
};

var logFactory = new LoggerFactory();
logFactory.AddAWSProvider(loggerConfig);

var logger = logFactory.CreateLogger<Infra.Logging>();
logger.LogInformation(logMessageString);
```

The `logMessageString` will be the string convert from JSON:

```
{
    "id": "001",
    "message": "Received Get Data Request",
    "logLevel": "Information"
}
```

The reason I want to remove is because I wish to query my log in Insight like:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter id="001"
| sort @timestamp desc
```

This query is not working now so I figured might be the default logged `[Information]` & `Infra.Logging` issue.

Appreciates any helps!

Comment: It will be good if you add few more logs along with relevant logs printed in CloudWatch Logs log group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your existing logging i.e. with `[Information] Infra.Logging:`  after that the further log message.
You can use `parse` command as shown below. For more details about parse command, please refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html) document from AWS.

Assumption: You have following logging structure;
[image]

One of possible solution is to execute aws cloud watch insight query as follows;

`fields @message | parse @message '[*] Infra.Logging: {"id": "*"' as @loggingType, @some_id | filter @loggingType='Information' and @some_id like '2' | sort @timestamp desc`

Output after execution aws cloud watch insight query is as follows;
[image]

Comment: Ok I will try this! Thank you!